# implementing threshold for bar graphs using flot api

Tags: jquery, graph, flot, threshold

i am using flot to plot a graph. i want to implement the functionality such that i am able to highlight a 10% growth in my graph showing in a different color other than the color i am using now. 
the code i am using is :

```
var options_blue = {
    series: {
        color: 'blue',
        threshold: { above: 5, color: 'green' },
        bars: { show: true, barWidth: 20 * 20 }
    },
    xaxis: { show: false, min: 1 },
    yaxis: { show: false, min: 1, max: max_value }
};

var options_red = {
    series: {
        color: '#ff0000',
        threshold: { above: 10, color:'green' },    
        bars: { show: true, barWidth: 20 * 20 }
    },
    threshold: { above: 5, color: "yellow" },
    xaxis: { show: false, min: 1 },
    yaxis: { show: false, min: 5, max: max_value }
};
```

I am using the jquery.flot.threshold.js, but there is no change in the graph colors beyond the threshold.

Answer (score 3):

You're using 'above', but the threshold plugin only supports 'below'.  So you just need to swap your series and threshold colors, and use 'below' instead.

Also note that in your options_red, you have a second threshold options outside of the series options.  The threshold plugin only looks for options within the series options, so that second one will get ignored.

Comment: i rectified the mistakes in the code. but still i am not able to plot the bar graph using jquery.flot.threshold.js 
When i use jquery.flot.threshold.min.js i am able to plot two different colors but the graph appears as a single line. 
provide any possible solutions to this.

Comment: You'll need to provide some more info; what do you mean by 'appears as a single line'?  What version of Flot are you using?  Are there any errors in the JS console?